# Group by classname in Console

Tags: java, system.out

I want to group my Console by classnames. Currently my Console prints stuff like this:

```
TraCheckController.java:
41: import de.ifdgmbh.wms.remote.model.views.VZone;
TraCheckController.java:
119:    *            {@link MapStringConverter} für {@link VZone} as {@link String}
TraCheckController.java:
417:    * {@link ListCellFactory} fuer die {@link VZone}en<br>
```

What do I have to change in my code in order to make my Console to look like this:

```
TraCheckController.java:
41: import de.ifdgmbh.wms.remote.model.views.VZone;
119:    *            {@link MapStringConverter} für {@link VZone} as {@link String}
417:    * {@link ListCellFactory} fuer die {@link VZone}en<br>
```

My code that handles the printing. It iterates trough every line of scripts and checks if some requirements are met or not:

```
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    for (String className : viewFileClassStrings) {
                        // Check if file contains the classname and the file is not a comment or a import statement
                        int index = line.indexOf(className);
                        if(index < 0) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        if (line.toCharArray()[index - 1] == 'I') {
                            continue;
                        }
                        if (line.contains("Fields")) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        if (line.contains(className)) {
                            System.out.println(child.getName() + ":");
                            System.out.println(String.format("\t%d:\t%s", currentLine, line.trim()));
                        }
                    }
                    currentLine++;
                }
```

Comment: Your loop doesn't contain the print statement for the first line so I assume that's ok in your opinion. If I understand you correctly you just don't want to print those other `TraCheckController.java:`, don't you? Is the code you've shown yours? If so you should understand what it does and not printing the class name again should be trivial. If it isn't your code please state so and try to explain what you're understanding it is doing.

Comment: The code is mine. You're right I don't want the other `TraCheckController.java` to appear in the console. At the bottom you see 2 println statements. The first one prints the `TraCheckController` which I only want it to do once. The second statement prints the line number and the line of code its currently reading.

Comment: Well, then just keep track if you printed the class name already, e.g. using a boolean, and don't print if you've done so already. If the code can iterate over more than 1 class, keep track of the last class name you've printed and check if the current one is the same - if so dont print, if not then print and keep track of this.